# unit tests: invoke test scripts from any directory

Tags: python, import, python-import, relative-path, python-unittest

I am trying to get my unit test scripts to work no matter where they are invoked from and have looked into a dozen questions on relative import issues now. But relative paths in combination with the unittest module seem to add some extra complications.

My directory structure is this:

```
importtest
├── importtest
│   ├── importtest.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── test
    ├── data.txt
    ├── importtest_test.py
    └── __init__.py
```

the `__init__.py` files are empty, `importtest.py` contains

```
def func(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return True
```

and `importtest_test.py` contains

```
import unittest
from importtest import importtest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        self.assertEqual(importtest.func('data.txt'), True)
```

This works when I execute `py -m unittest test/importtest_test.py` from the root folder of the project (the top most `importtest` folder). But it does not work from any other directory.

Why is that and how can I fix this?

Comment: When you say any directory do you outside your project folder as well?

Comment: Yes. But it also does not work from inside any directory within the project folder other than the root foler.

Comment: That's an import issue, therefore if you want to run it in a folder that is in your project folder use `from ..foo import foo` the .. tells python to move up one directory when importing. Just like .. in bash

Comment: But I don't want to hardcode that. I want it to figure that out by itself.

Comment: checkout the answer to this question, might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path